# Which .NET and PHP CMSs are able to run on Rackspace Cloud CloudSites (formerly Mosso)?

Tags: rackspace, mosso

I have scoured the internet to find which CMS's run on CloudSites and the only definitive information I have found is on RackspaceClouds knowledge base
http://help.rackspacecloud.com/article.php?id=383

Only BlogEngine, DotNetNuke & AspDotNetStoreFront are listed.

Does anyone know of any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal runs on there OK

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but wanted to give an update on this and provide some updated information. The below link has articles for installing the popular Content Management Systems i.e. Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, Magento, and more.

[CMS Install Articles](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/product-articles/cloud-sites#25)

You can also visit [Rackspace Knowledge Base](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_base) for more information to any questions that might come up for Cloud Sites as well.